# "Go To File" keyboard short cut have disappeared from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have tried to changed the short cut for "Go To File" command,
and might have deleted it by mistake.
how can I restore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `Keyboard Shortcuts` UI open (from the Gear icon), click on the odd `Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` icon on the right of the tab bar (or trigger the exact same command from the Command Palette).

In that file you will find something like:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+e",
  "command": "-workbench.action.quickOpen"
},
```

(just do a find for that command).  Delete that negated keybinding - note the leading `-` before the command which removes it (or comment it out) and it will reactivate.